# Installshield limited edition - How to remove old version?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield

I'm setting up a installation (.exe) for Office Plugin and using Installshield limited edition. I have old version 1.0 was distributed and used by end-user, right now I would like to redistribute new version 2.0, and would like to make program to remove or override completely old version when install new version.

I tried "upgrade path" to change product code but it seem does not override completely old version.

Does anyone can help or let me know there is any way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got solution now. Beside change Product Code & Product version I have to change INSTALLDIR path to resolve it.

Step to do it:

- Step 1: From installshield => Select upgrade path => add new => Browse to old version (.exe), to get Upgrade Code. If the app support multi-language with multiple install file (.exe) version we need to add all these old version in  upgrade path
- Step 2: From installshield go to "General Information Tab" to check make sure Upgrade Code is the same, then change product code and Product Version
- Step 3: From installshield go to "General Information Tab" to change INSTALLDIR path for new version, for example from MyApp1.0 to MyApp2.0